# How can I trigger Google Spreadsheets script if a specific cell contains a value greater than, say, 10

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a script that would launch an e-mail, and I want it to be run when a specific cell (A5) contains a value over 10. Here's the script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rownum = 1; // #of rows
  var rowstart = 2; // where to start row

  // get range of cell
  // column 1 = email, column 2 is first name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(rowstart, 1, rownum, 2)


  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  for (i in data) {
    if(sheet.getRange(5,1).getValue()>10){      //change row and column in get range to match what you need
      var row = data[i];
      var emailadr = row[0]; // data select
      var msgcontent = "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n Just:)chilling \n    Sent from my email"; // body
      var sbjt = "You have mail!"; //subject
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailadr, sbjt, msgcontent);}
    }
  }
```

Under Current project's triggers, I have the following:

> Run: onEdit
>
> Events: From spreadsheet On edit

Now, when I set cell "A5" to "21", the script doesn't run. What's the issue? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: It may be a problem of installable trigger. Was ``onEdit()`` installed as a trigger? When it isn't done, ``authMode=LIMITED``. So e-mail cannot be used.

Comment: Firstly, have you tried to run the function by itself without relying on the trigger? Does it work? Secondly, your code is designed to send  mail to everyone on the list each time you edit anywhere on the sheet. Is that the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using logger it shows that it does work. You can see in example below. You may want to try to use a time based trigger and set it to check every x amount of time and send email. Google may not allow the sendemail to run "onedit"

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rownum = 1; // #of rows
  var rowstart = 2; // where to start row

  // get range of cell
  // column 1 = email, column 2 is first name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(rowstart, 1, rownum, 2)


  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  
  
 for (i in data) {
   if(sheet.getRange(5,1).getValue()>10){      //change row and column in get range to match what you need
     var row = data[i];
         Logger.log("Yes it is larger than 10");
      
    //  var emailadr = row[0]; // data select
    //  var msgcontent = "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n Just:)chilling \n    Sent from my email"; // body
    //  var sbjt = "You have mail!"; //subject
    //   MailApp.sendEmail(emailadr, sbjt, msgcontent);
   }
  }
}
```